# Forge CSS are changing all table headers of my web app

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

There is a style in Forge Viewer v7.2.1 that changes all table headers of my Vue.js web application.

The problematic selector is:

```
.adsk-viewing-viewer .datatable table td, th
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent Forge CSS from changing the td border colors of my entire application?

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear from the contents of this post. Please see the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page if you need some help.

Comment: @Das_Geek maybe I had posted this in a wrong place. I have a workaround solution, I'm just reporting the problem to help Autodesk Forge Users and to notify the Forge Dev Team.

Comment: yeah this site is really only a question-and-answer forum, not a place to simply report problems. I would probably suggest removing this post.

Comment: @Das_Geek now it is a question. I will wait for some Autodesk Forge expert to try to help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you narrow specifically to your table with class names then Viewer's global styling won't take precedence (regardless of Viewer or your stylesheets get loaded first):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Alternatively you can load your stylesheet after that of Viewer so your styling overrides Viewer's in case of overlaps/conflicts.

Nonetheless I will let Engineering know to fix the class prefix for table headers. Thanks for reporting the issue and as the comments pointed out for similar problem reports please send them to forge.help@autodesk.com.